# Perl Grep issue in nested hash/array

Tags: perl

I want to remove values which contain "local" string in their value. here is my hash output (`print Dumper ($hash)`):

```
$VAR1 = {
          'FARM_03' => [
                           'nfs01',
                           'nfs02',
                           'nfs03',
                           'localvmfs',
                           'localvmfs'
                           ],
          'FARM_07' => [
                           'nfs01',
                           'localvmfs',
                           'localvmfs'
                           ],
          'FARM_11' => [
                           'nfs01',
                           'localvmfs',
                           'localvmfs'
                           ]
        };
```

Hence I wrote below code in my script to omit the "local" entries:

```
foreach my $key ( keys %$hash )
{
    @{ $hash->{key} } = grep { !/local/i } @{ $hash->{key} };
}
```

and here is the output after running above grep command:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'FARM_03' => [
                           'nfs01',
                           'nfs02',
                           'nfs03',
                           'localvmfs',
                           'localvmfs'
                           ],
          'FARM_07' => [
                           'nfs01',
                           'localvmfs',
                           'localvmfs'
                           ],
          'FARM_11' => [
                           'nfs01',
                           'localvmfs',
                           'localvmfs'
                           ]
          'key' => []
    };
```

It is not removing the "local" entries as well as it adds a new field `'key' => []`.

Could you tell me what is wrong with my grep statement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `{key}` where you mean `{$key}` (twice).